# Common Interface to implement!C#-Winform

Tags: c#, oop, interface

There are lots of interfaces in C#.which are the most common interfaces ,we have to learn :)

Comment: Please be much more specific... currently this is not really a question.

Comment: I am new to C#,winforms.While learning lots of interfaces comes and i am confused whether to learn all of them or the important ones :)

Comment: You will learn them as you go...

Comment: Why you ask this? Maybe knowing your motivation we can give you better information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, `IComparable`, `IDisposable`

Comment: Also consider generics: `IComparable<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, etc.

Comment: I'd even say the non generic versions of those interfaces(except `IDsposable` of course) are much less important than there generic counterparts.

Comment: Thank you .now i have to explore the generic version of interface :)